# How can I make my validation class extendible?

Tags: php, oop, class, inheritance, scope

I am writing a validation class in PHP which I would like to be extendible without editing the main parent class. I have provided a simplified version below of what I hope to achieve. I am passing a function/method name to validate() which first checks if it exists and if it does invokes it to check the variable I passed is valid. I am new to OOP and having problems with scope / visibility as I'm unable to get any custom validation rules in the child class working without hardcoding the name of the child class in the parent class. What is the best way to go about this? Many thanks for any assistance you can provide.

```
$rule = "number";
$var = "abcdef";

class  Validation
{
    public static function validate($rule, $var) {
        if (is_callable("self::{$rule}")) {
            return self::$rule($var);
        }
    }

    protected static function number($var) {
        return (preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/i", $var));
    }
}

class MyRules extends Validation
{   
    public static function letter($var) {       
        return (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+$/i", $var));
    }
}

print MyRules::validate($rule, $var) ? "Valid!" : "Not valid!"; // Not valid!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can prevent overriding of the `validate` method using the `final` keyword:

```
public static final function validate($rule, $var) {
```

As for not being able to call static methods of subclasses, this can be done using [Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php):

```
class Validation {
    public static final function validate($rule, $var) {
        if (is_callable("static::$rule")) {
            return static::$rule($var);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I never knew you could do this! Very useful. I think you missed out one colon on the static:: keyword

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [strategy design pattern](http://www.fluffycat.com/PHP-Design-Patterns/Strategy/). It can be used if you want different variants of an algorithm, in your case the validation.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looks like a useful resource.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i work with my self made framework / libraries :

Like most n-tier systems , (MVC is like that) , the data must be checked b4 it is passed to the back-end tier(the database) ... so in a mvc arhitecture u can make a model that is the corespoindent to a db table , put in there the queries connection and validation... That model class needs to know only about that table data and nothing more...

If ull get to a point and see that ur validations get to some kind of routine... u can make a library... Or u can think from start what kind of data will ur app have...

P.S. : so for each data type in a table write a the correspondent validation, if the validations repeat make a library and call the lib validation method for the coresponding db data type

Comment: This is certainly a valid way of working. I just assumed this would be part of his own library though.

Comment: its pritty hard to make a lib about validation... its hard to get an ideea from start what type of data will ur app have... ofc depends on the scale...

Comment: The validation class I am writing is to complement a form generation class that I am putting together, as a learning exercise more than anything, although it's shaping up pretty well and I'll be using it in my projects.